'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.' when changing the contentview
The app is crashing randomly when changing the contentview inside the carouselview, I tried to see if there was something wrong with the code but couldnt find anything.
I'm trying to mimic a tabbedpage and I chose not to use it since I was having lots of problems with the icons, if possible can anyone help me please?
`
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ContentPages}" Position="{Binding CurrentPosition}"
                  PositionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectButtonCommand}"
                  PositionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding CurrentPosition}" Loop="False">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>


public class DashboardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int _currentPosition;
    public ObservableCollection<ContentView> ContentPages { get; set; }
    public ICommand SelectButtonCommand { get; }
    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        ContentPages = new ObservableCollection<ContentView>()
        {
            new Profile(),
            new Books(),
            new Chat(),
            new Feed(),
            new Configuration(),
            new Menu()
        };
        SelectButtonCommand = new Command<int>(SelectButton);
    }
    public int CurrentPosition
    {
        get => _currentPosition;
        set
        {
            if (_currentPosition != value)
            {
                _currentPosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPosition));
            }
        }
    }
}
`

I tried to change the contentviews to contentpages but it didnt work, also tried to add handlers but I dont know how to use them, other then the crashes the code is working fine.

You can refer to this issue: CarouselView - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

The code you shared doesn't show how you are changing the views. However, based on the error you shared in you title, the issue is that you are trying to add a view that has already been added. Without more code, is hard to help you more.

The view change is being done by the carouselview since I'm using the ObservableCollection as its itemsource. Srry I forgot to add the xaml

@LiyunZhang-MSFT but Vannoctar2 asked his question at the end which is exacly the problem I'm having, then he just closed the issue. I also tried to look into the other mentioned issues, but I couldn't quite understand them, and from what I understood what I'm trying to do was possible in XF but it wasn't intended to and now we are supposed to bind the data instead of the views, is this correct?

Based on the code snippets you shared, I created a demo, but I could not reproduce this problem. Could you please share more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

@JessieZhang-MSFT I'll create a demo and will post the link as soon as possible

@JessieZhang-MSFT since the code got pretty lenghty I made a repository on github, here's the link: https://github.com/JoaoCarlosBessa/DemoApp. Sorry for the trouble but I needed to copy almost everything from the main app, and apparently the exception started to appear after I added the 4th contentview to the list

I downloaded the sample and test it on android simulator some times. But this error didn't appear.

if you guys can't reproduce the problem maybe it's related to the processing power of my device since it's not that "strong", I'll try it on a more potent device and see if it will crash there

Waiting for your news. :)

After testing for a bit, it looks like it is a perfomance issue since when I used phones with 8GB+ of RAM the app didn't crash, still I'd like to solve this issue for the weaker phones so if you guys are willing to help I'd be really grateful
